# Scroll Linear view above Listview android

Tags: android, listview

I want to scroll the View above the ListView.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.thakormatrimony.user.Search"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarSearch"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewSearchCriteria"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSearchCriteria"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextSearchByName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/label_search_by_name"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="100px"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"/>
                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="100px"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerSubCast" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100px"
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerDegree" />
                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="100px"
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerCurrentCity" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="100px"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerBirthYearFrom"/>
                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="100px"
                            android:id="@+id/spinnerBirthYearTo" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/title_activity_search"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
                        android:id="@+id/viewLine1" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listViewSeachProfiles"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutSearchCriteria">
                </ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The area marked with red border is `ListView` and its scrolling but I want scroll the view yellow border view with `ListView` scroll. For example like tweeter. Its like when I scroll `ListView` it'll scroll the search option view on top.

[image]

Comment: What is the behaviour right now? Is not scrolling at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `views` you want to scroll inside the `ScrollView` directly. So, swap the `RelativeLayout` and the `ScrollView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp">
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewSearchCriteria"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
```